# Sorting an array using Array.sort() without a comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have to sort an Array of custom objects by one of the object's params using Arrays.sort() , but WITHOUT passing a Comparator. This is a homework assignment and my professor wants us to do it without a comparator.

To be more specific I have an array[] of object type 'Female', female is made up of params 'name' and 'age'. I have to sort the array by age using `Arrays.sort(femaleList)`, but again I cannot use a Comparator.

I'm trying to use .getAge() or something like that, but it's not working. I'm assuming there's some relatively simple solution that I'm overlooking, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, implement [`Comparable<Female>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) like

```
class Female implements Comparable<Female> {
    // ...
    public int compareTo(Female that) {
        if (this.age < that.age) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.age > that.age) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you make the last line

```
return this.name.compareTo(that.name);
```

it will sort by `name` if any are the same age.

Comment: You can just implement it as this.age - that.age.

Comment: @MattPutnam Please don't recommend that, it isn't exactly wrong about `Comparable` but it breaks the [`Comparator.compare(T, T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) contract which *is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive*.

Comment: This worked! I knew it was something simple, my professor went over this in class but, I didn't fully grasp the difference between this and making a specific comparator class, now I do. Anyways thanks very much for the help! :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I can't find that requirement in your link.  Where does it say you must return -1, 0, or 1?

Comment: @CandiedOrange It's a direct quote from the linked javadoc. It's a part of the second sentence, which reads in full *In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes and the sentence just before that doesn't actually have a sgn notation in it.  It actually says: "Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."  No mention of sgn.  Which is a little confusing since that is the "foregoing description".  I'm hoping you can clear this up.  This document goes into relations that must hold.  Are you claiming that sticking to -1. 0. 1 avoids all those problems?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I didn't write the documentation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no but you are using it to support an argument.  I'm honestly asking why it's important to do it the -1, 0, 1 way.

Comment: @CandiedOrange There are really two issues. Issue 1: Negative ages break your subtraction method. Not relevant because ages shouldn't be negative, but what if it was some other `int` field. Issue 2: What if someone is using strict equality testing, if (result == -1); works with every bit of Java from Oracle. Breaks in your example because it won't be `-1` (or if someone has that in a `switch` case).

Comment: @Elliot Frisch the second argument is invalid as then the caller of the interface method doesn't adhere to the contract. As said before, the contract doesn't require you to return exactly 1, but a positive integer suffices. The sign operator is used only to express that reversing the arguments must have the effect that the method will return any integer of the opposite sign. Your first argument is valid though, it is a puzzler from Java Puzzlers where the difference between two integers overflows.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I think I have the documentation confusion figured out.  The second paragraph is in the wrong place.  They only used -1, 0, 1 to define the sgn() function mentioned in the documentation.  They never required you to return sgn().  This has the paragraph in the right place: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 2):

It can be as simple as this:

```
class Female implements Comparable<Female> {
    // ...
    public int compareTo(Female that) {
        return this.age - that.age;
    }
}
```

Because all you have to return is:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Be aware that this implementation comes with risks.  This assumes that subtracting ages will not cause an overflow which could happen if their signs differ (essentially making this addition) and the sum of their magnitude was greater than age's type can hold.

> Another important point to note is don't use subtraction for comparing
>   integral values because result of subtraction can overflow as every
>   int operation in Java is modulo 2^32. use either Integer.compareTo() 
>   or logical operators for comparison. There is one scenario where you
>   can use subtraction to reduce clutter and improve performance. As we
>   know compareTo doesn't care magnitude, it just care whether result is
>   positive or negative. While comparing two integral fields you can use
>   subtraction if you are absolutely sure that both operands are positive
>   integer or more precisely [their difference] must be less than
>   Integer.MAX_VALUE. In this case there will be no overflow and your
>   compareTo will be concise and faster.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-override-compareto-method-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `Female` implement `Comparable`.

Comment: And then make a compareTo() method or compare() method in the Female class?

Comment: Yes, as per the Comparable specification.